# Foreach on table row

Tags: foreach, codeigniter-2

Im using mPDF to generate PDFs and send reports to the clients.

I'm using this foreach to fill my table row

```
    $report_nr = $this->input->post('report_nr');
        $date = $this->input->post('date');
        $owner = $this->input->post('owner');
        $ar1 = $this->input->post('column01');
        $ar2 = $this->input->post('column02');
        $ar3 = $this->input->post('column03');
        $ar4 = $this->input->post('column04');
        $ar5 = $this->input->post('column05');
        $ar6 = $this->input->post('column06');
        $ar7 = $this->input->post('column07');
        $ar8 = $this->input->post('column08');
        $ar9 = $this->input->post('column09');
        $ar10 = $this->input->post('column10');

        include('../mpdf.php');
        $mpdf = new mPDF('',    // mode - default ''
            'A4',    // format - A4, for example, default ''
            0,     // font size - default 0
            '',    // default font family
            15,    // margin_left
            15,    // margin right
            16,     // margin top
            16,    // margin bottom
            9,     // margin header
            9,     // margin footer
            'P');  // L - landscape, P - portrait
        //$this->customer_report();
        $n=0; //start counting at 0, like array counters do.
        foreach ($ar2 as $thing) { //for each value of $ar2
        $bigar[$n][2] = $thing; //set $bigarray at $n at 1 to that part
        $n++; //add one to $n, continue
        }
        $n=0; //repeat for array 3
        foreach ($ar3 as $thing) {
        $bigar[$n][3] = $thing; //now use the 2 value of the array
        $n++;
        }
        $n=0; //repeat for array 4
        foreach ($ar5 as $thing) {
        $bigar[$n][5] = $thing; //now use the 2 value of the array
        $n++;
        }
        $n=0; //start counting at 0, like array counters do.
        foreach ($ar6 as $thing) { //for each value of $ar2
        $bigar[$n][6] = $thing; //set $bigarray at $n at 1 to that part
        $n++; //add one to $n, continue
        }
        $n=0; //repeat for array 3
        foreach ($ar8 as $thing) {
        $bigar[$n][8] = $thing; //now use the 2 value of the array
        $n++;
        }
        $n=0; //repeat for array 4
        foreach ($ar9 as $thing) {
        $bigar[$n][9] = $thing; //now use the 2 value of the array
        $n++;
        }
        $n=0; //repeat for array 1
        foreach ($ar1 as $thing) {
        $bigar[$n][1] = $thing; //now use the 2 value of the array
        $n++;
        }
        $this->mpdf->WriteHTML("<table border='1'>");
        $this->mpdf->WriteHTML('<thead><tr><th class="span1">Relatório Nº :</th><th>&nbsp;'.$report_nr.'&nbsp;</th><th>Data :</th><th>&nbsp;'.$date.'&nbsp;</th><th>Cliente :</th><th colspan="5">&nbsp;'.$owner.'&nbsp;</th></tr></thead>');
        $this->mpdf->WriteHTML("<tbody>");
        $this->mpdf->WriteHTML("<tr>");
        foreach ($bigar as $part) { //go through each chunk of the array
          if($i%10 == 0 && $i != 0) { 
            $this->mpdf->WriteHTML("</tr>");
            $this->mpdf->WriteHTML("<tr>");
          }
        $this->mpdf->WriteHTML("<td>");
        $this->mpdf->WriteHTML("<table><tbody><tr><td>&nbsp;".($part[2]+$part[3])."&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;".($part[5]+$part[6])."&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;".($part[8]+$part[9]).'&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;'.$part[1]."&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table>");
        $this->mpdf->WriteHTML("</td>"); //now, like above, that part has [1], and [2]
        $i++;
        }
        $this->mpdf->WriteHTML("</tr>");
        $this->mpdf->WriteHTML("</tbody></table>");
```

As u can see on the last row...when i reach 10 cells, it create another row.
Now i need the last row to get to 10 cells even if no content on the arrays, otherwise it won't create the complete row, which makes my table a mess in the end...

Here's a printscreen of the pdf:

[image: PrintScreen]

Hope i made myself clear.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way of doing it and i want to share with u.

```
    }
    $this->mpdf->WriteHTML('<table border="1">');
    $this->mpdf->WriteHTML('<thead><tr><th>Relatório Nº :</th><th>&nbsp;'.$report_nr.'&nbsp;</th><th>Data :</th><th>&nbsp;'.$date.'&nbsp;</th><th>Cliente :</th><th colspan="5">&nbsp;'.$owner.'&nbsp;</th></tr></thead>');
    $this->mpdf->WriteHTML("<tbody>");
    $this->mpdf->WriteHTML("<tr>");
    foreach ($bigar as $part) { //go through each chunk of the array
      if($i%10 == 0 && $i != 0) { 
        $this->mpdf->WriteHTML('</tr>');
        $this->mpdf->WriteHTML('<tr>');
      }

    $this->mpdf->WriteHTML("<td>");
    $this->mpdf->WriteHTML("<table border='1'><tbody><tr><td>&nbsp;".($part[2]+$part[3])."&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;".($part[5]+$part[6])."&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;".($part[8]+$part[9]).'&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;'.$part[1]."&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table>");
    $this->mpdf->WriteHTML("</td>"); //now, like above, that part has [1], and [2]


    $i++;

    }
    $this->mpdf->WriteHTML('<td colspan="'.(10-($i%10)).'"></td></tr>');
    $this->mpdf->WriteHTML("</tbody></table>");
    //$bigar_removed = ereg_replace("0", "", $bigar);
    //$this->mpdf->WriteHTML("".$bigar_removed."");
        $this->mpdf->WriteHTML("<pagebreak>");

        $this->mpdf->Output();
        exit;
    }
```

The trick was find a way of know which cell number was last created in the row.

```
    $this->mpdf->WriteHTML('<td colspan="'.(10-($i%10)).'"></td></tr>');
```

This way, i just substracted the number from 10, which left me with the number to use with coldspan, having the row complete.

Hope it helps some of u!!

Thank you all